# Can Esika, God of the Tree ever cheat the back side of a double-sided card into play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I have played The Prismatic Bridge (the back face of [Esika, God of the Tree](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Esika%2C%20God%20of%20the%20Tree)), an enchantment which has "At the beginning of your upkeep, reveal cards from the top of your library until you reveal a creature or planeswalker card. Put that card onto the battlefield and the rest on the bottom of your library in a random order."

Now suppose that the card revealed this way is [Valki, God of Lies](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Valki%2C%20God%20of%20Lies) - which is a double-faced card with Tibalt, Cosmic Imposter on the back.  Can I put Tibalt, Cosmic Imposter into play instead of Valki?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - The Prismatic Bridge specifically tells you to put the card onto the battlefield, double faced cards being put onto the battlefield without being played (lands) or cast (spells) are put into play front face up unless otherwise specified (put into play transformed, or daybound/nightbound). This is covered by rule 712.10:

> ***712.10*** A double-faced card put onto the battlefield from a zone other than the stack enters the battlefield with its front face up by default.
>
> > ***712.10a*** If a spell or ability puts a transforming double-faced card onto the battlefield “transformed,” it enters the battlefield with its back face up. If a player is instructed to put a card that isn’t a transforming double-faced card onto the battlefield transformed, that card stays in its current zone.
> >
> > ***712.10b*** If a player is instructed to put a modal double-faced card onto the battlefield and its front face isn’t a permanent card, the card stays in its current zone.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Andrew's answer, this is addressed explicitly on the linked Gatherer  page:

> If you reveal a double-faced card whose front face is a creature or planeswalker, you'll put it onto the battlefield with its front face up.

along with other general double-faced card clarifications like

> If an effect puts a double-faced card onto the battlefield, it enters with its front face up. If that front face can't be put onto the battlefield, it doesn't enter the battlefield.